# What could cause a large number of Timeout objects to be retained in heapdumps for a NodeJS heapdump?

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, heap-dump, circuit-breaker

For the past few months, my service has struggled with memory issues. Upon analyzing the heapdumps, I see that `Timeout` takes up a large amount of retained memory, usually about 70%, while the shallow memory is actually about 29%. When I expand the retainers of one of the `Timeout` objects, I see a cascading `_idlePrev in Timeout`, some of them cascade for a lot longer than this. For context, the app is a NodeJS Express app and we use opossum as a circuit breaker and Node Fetch to make requests. I know that's not nearly enough information to diagnose the issue, but I was wondering if anyone has seen anything like this and what could cause a stack like this to be retained in memory.
[image]

Comment: Is your service under stress?  You should share more details to help you: package.json, nodejs & npm version, os. Also If you are able to reproduce the issue with a hello world, share us as github repository.